# Shortcut to open/focus terminal window

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I am using shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for opening a new Terminal window. I am using one of the terminal very often (calculator and simple commands) and I want to set up another shortcut (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or any other, I don't care) to switch to this specific terminal window (using gnome-terminal in Unity, Ubuntu 12.04).

Is this possible (and how)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an application called `wmctrl`, which can help you. You can install wmctrl by command:

```
# apt-get install wmctrl
```

You can get list of currently existing windows by `wmctrl -l` and see titles and names of currently existing windows. Using titles, you can raise a window by:

```
$ wmctrl -a <string>
```

To automatize this procedure, you can start specific gnome-terminal with --title parameter to set its window title. Assuming you've run:

```
$ gnome-terminal --title=testing
```

You can run:

```
$ wmctrl -a "testing"
```

to raise that window, beware of that the string you used to select window should be specific to that window, shouldn't match with any other window's title.

Answer (score 4):

I've written a small program called [`jumpapp`](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp) for exactly this purpose. It lets you create **one keyboard shortcut** to opens a new terminal the first time you press it, and to switch to the already open window any time you press it after that. As a bonus, if you have multiple terminal windows open, repeatedly pressing the shortcut will cycle through all the terminal windows.

[image]

It's easy to [install from source](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp#from-source), or you can install it from my PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkropat/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jumpapp
```

Comment: This looks awesome but for me it says there is no package available. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You'll have to install from source (don't worry -- it's not too complicated). I don't think Ubuntu will let me upload a package to my PPA for 12.04 anymore.